# SQL for filtering records with part of value is same

Tags: sql

I don't have much expertise in SQL. I want to filter the records from the table with the below criteria.

i want to separate out the records in the below example with result showing as "KLMNP03" and "UVXYZ03". 
there are similar records with last chars as 03 and 04, but I want to just filter out those records with only 03 at the end

for example:

```
col1
---------
ABCDE03
ABCDE04
KLMNP03
LMNOP03
LMNOP04
UVXYZ03
```

Comment: But you don't want ABCDE03, also ending with 03?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your use case is, but this is pretty inefficient. It's better to use whole columns. In any case, to do what you are asking for:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    yourTable
WHERE   col1 NOT LIKE ( '%03' )
```

This will return everything that does not have 03 at the end.

% is a wild card character, and represents any number of characters before the normal characters. You can do something similar with the _ character, which represents a single random character.

In SQLServer at least. It may be different in other RDBMs

Comment: Thank you for your response LordBaconPants, I want to list only those records which are having 03 and no equivalent 04 records with first 5 chars are same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results with only 03 at the end, use this query:

```
SELECT  *FROM    yourTable WHERE   col1 LIKE ('%03')
```

This will return Following results:

1. ABCDE03
2. KLMNP03
3. LMNOP03
4. UVXYZ03

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I didn't framed my question correctly.

I want to list those records which are having '03' at the end and with out '04' parallel record (in the same column) in the table.

Comment: Hi, Any idea how can filter those records?

Comment: what do you mean by "and with out '04' parallel record (in the same column) in the table".

Comment: I mean, in the same column I have both the records as,  
ABCDE03
ABCDE04
KLMNP03
LMNOP03
LMNOP04
UVXYZ03 , some of them are having both 03 and 04 with same first 5 chars. I want only those records that are having 03 with out immediate 04 record.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I think I didn't framed my question correctly.

I want to list those records which are having '03' at the end and with out '04' parallel record (in the same column) in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 WITH cte AS(
 SELECT col, 1 AS r FROM #tbl   
 ),
 cte2 AS(
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN (LEAD(col) OVER (ORDER BY r) NOT LIKE '%04' OR LEAD(col) OVER (ORDER BY r) IS NULL )AND col LIKE '%03'
                THEN col
            ELSE
                NULL
        END AS col
    FROM cte t
 )

 SELECT * FROM cte2 WHERE col IS NOT NULL
```

Replace `#tbl` with your table name and `col` to your column name.